# Transfer of Liquid from one dish to another

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word for the act of transferring liquid from one dish  to another  repetitively in order to cool it.

Comment: How could this cool something more quickly than just letting it sit? (Perhaps due to a greater surface area of the liquid in contact with cooler air?) In any case, if you posted a link to this actual practice with an explanation it *might* help in finding a word or short phrase for it.

Comment: @Jason quote a lot of extra surface area, mixing, the heat capacity of 2 vessels, airflow causing more evaporative cooling

Comment: WikiHow calls it just "Transferring Between Cups":  https://www.wikihow.com/Cool-a-Hot-Drink-Quickly

Comment: @Kris but on the other hand that's one of the most inane articles I've read on wikihow, and that's saying something

Comment: @Jason Here is a link for a picture of this act which is pretty common in India.  https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.ckwtaMK2_3UI9di0JqyJ4gHaJ4&w=131&h=169&c=7&o=5&pid=1.7There is such a word in English

Comment: Sorry, there, I pressed <Enter> before I could finish.  I came across that word recently but am unfortunately not able to recollect. As far as I can recall it begins with the letter 'C' . Not that this information would be of much help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll get a single word, because it's not a common enough action. I doubt you want a single word though, as you'll have to introduce the concept.

Some variation on *pouring back and forth* or *pouring between* is probably your best bet.

I've worked with engineers who do this to cool their coffee, and we didn't have a specific term. These were people with a wide vocabulary and a tendency to use/invent colourful phrases and portmanteaus.

Comment: Rather than "pour"-ing," it's more like "air"-ing your coffee I feel.

Comment: @Kris, that's the goal, but it doesn't describe the action very well.  *Airing* would suggest leaving it out exposed to fresh air for some time, and isn't normally applied to liquids (or foods, with a few exceptions).  You're actually [*areating*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_aeration) it (as boiling removes dissolved gas), but that's not the primary goal so again not a good fit. Simply *cooling* isn't specific enough but would do once the process had been explained.

Comment: Ok, "air cooling" be it, then.

Comment: @Kris I like that, you should post it as an answer to give the OP a choice (unless of course you believe strictly in only answering "single-word-request" Qs with single words)